# API v3 Include Some Tags and Exclude Others

Tags: api, tags

I can do a custom search on Contacts to include those with a list of tags, and exclude those that also have an additional tag. And I get the results I expect.

I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this with the API, though. The API Explorer won't allow me to add 'tags' as a parameter twice, so I can't figure out how to do the construction.

For example, I want to match all contacts that have tag ID 12, but exclude those that also have tag ID 7.

Something like
`'tag' => ['IN' => $tags_included, 'NOT IN' => $tags_excluded]`

Comment: Once you get the results from the "IN", you could just do a plain old `foreach` code loop to filter out the "NOT IN".

Comment: Interestingly the api4 explorer (/civicrm/api4) appears to make this very easy, except I can't get it to work and I always get 0 results. Possibly related to this issue, which is different but might be a similar cause: https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.api4/issues/128

Comment: And I can do this through a custom search easily, as well. How does the custom search function? Does it not use the API internally?

Comment: The custom search does some procedural steps creating a temporary table and raw SQL. It does not use api3. In fact I'm sure it was written before api3, and possibly even api2. https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/5.14.2/CRM/Contact/Form/Search/Custom/Group.php#L399-L478 (see - only 80 lines of code!)